# Is this possible in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedures

I would like to get the no of rows based on their ids. So i create a sample procedure in MySQL.This is not working for me. Please help me to get this.

```
 DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteObjectTypes(IN p_type VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM TMPTBL WHERE FLD_ID IN (p_type);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

This show the first record only. Please help me to get this..

Comment: What query do you use to obtain those IDs in the first place?

Comment: Is p_type VARCHAR(255) a comma separated INT values?

Comment: yes comma separated int values.

Comment: I can tell you why it's not working. Whether you can fix it, depends on you. Assuming you have two IDs - 1 and 2, what your procedure will do is this: `SELECT * FROM TMPTBL WHERE FLD_ID IN('1, 2');`. What you need it to do is `SELECT * FROM TMPTBL WHERE FLD_ID IN(1, 2);`. I don't know whether you see the subtle difference or not, but that kills the point of your procedure. Which brigs me back to my original question - *what* query do you use to obtain those IDs?

Answer (score 0):

Try using dynamic sql:

```
@Query="SELECT * FROM TMPTBL WHERE FLD_ID IN ("+p_type+");"
EXEC(@Query);
```

Comment: Yes comma separated only.

Comment: @user3085540: You need to declare the variable `@Query` as `varchar(MAX)`. Try `SELECT(@Query)` instead of `EXEC(@Query)` to verify the query is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `p_type` will be taken as a single `varchar`.

If you are passing `1,2` as `p_type` it is passed as `'1,2'`

what you need really is `'1','2'` .

So add escape sequence to seprate it into pieces and execute using a prepare statement

You have to concat `escape sequence` `'\'`  to the string you are passing before executing the prepare statement.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteObjectTypes(IN p_type VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SET p_type = replace(p_type,',','\',\'');
SET @SQL =  CONCAT("SELECT * FROM TMPTBL WHERE FLD_ID  IN ('",p_type,"')");
prepare stmt from @SQL;
execute  stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```